# Cardinalities of generating sets for finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. A set $S \subseteq G$ is called a *generating set* for $G$ if every element of $G$ can be written as a product of elements of $S\cup S^{-1}$. Call $S$ a *minimal generating set* for $G$ if there is no proper subset of $S$ which is a generating set for $G$. Different minimal generating sets can have different cardinalities. For example, $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$ are both minimal generating sets for $\mathbb{Z}$.

> Is there an example of a **finite** group $G$ with two minimal generating sets with different cardinalities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the symmetric group $S_n$ is generated by an order $2$ element and an order $n$ element. But also $\{(12),(13),\dots,(1n)\}$ generates all of the order $2$ elements, and any element of $S_n$ can be represented as a product of order $2$ elements.

For an abelian example, consider $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$; both $\{1+15\mathbb Z\}$ and $\{3+15\mathbb Z,5+15\mathbb Z\}$ are minimal generating sets.